# What is the real meaning of coitus

Tags: meaning, expressions

I want to know the real meaning of this word.
I searched this word on google, but there are porn images are there.
I don't want see that.
Hope kind explaination on here.

Comment: You probably have too many cookies stored in your browser!  It means sexual intercourse.

Comment: Have you tried using an online dictionary (most of those aren't illustrated)?

Comment: You can do better than that. Here is a [dictionary definition](https://www.lexico.com/definition/coitus).

Comment: User a dictionary!

Comment: Search for "coitus definition" instead. You will get the answers you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the plain fact, as has been reminded you in the comments, that it means "(sexual) intercourse" or more or less synonymously "copulation", you might be wondering at the meaning of the morphemes found in the word, which a good dictionary will also provide you with. From the SOED (1995 ed.) you can gather the following interesting etymological facts at the entry "coition": [L *coitio(n)*, from *coit* past participle stem of *coire*, from as CO- + *ire* go]; as "CO-" means "with others" the word "coitus", taken from the latin verb "coit",  meaning basically "to go with others",  means "a going with others", "a going together", and this is rather remote from the actual sense of the word in English.